# Div that shows regular search filters does not come up on jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I posted this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340984/going-from-advanced-job-search-to-regular-filter-search-doesnt-display-filter (although I deleted this original question because it was not clear).

But I don't think I am being clear on what the issue is.  I could try to edit that question but it would be rewriting the question.  I'm not sure the team is getting what I am trying to say.

**I already know you guys do not support both advanced search entered into the textbox WITH the guided search filters**.  This is not my issue.  My issue is the following...

Lets say you started a job search using the advanced search..that is you start with:

`title:"search engineer"` and hit enter

[image]

Good so far as you have performed an advanced search using the `title` field.  Now click the first result "Java Search Engineer".  I am taken to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/121946/java-search-engineer-kayak?offset=0&q=title%3a%22search+engineer%22

Now click the hyperlink that looks like a double arrow and says `<< search results` this will take you back to your prior search results.

Now remove the advanced search by making your search simply `search engineer` instead of `title:"search engineer"` and hit enter...

Now try to click that button that allows you to add compensation, companies, pay scale, etc...it no longer opens look here:

[image]

Clicking this icon does this:

[image]

So the bug here is that although I have changed back to regular search (not advanced search) the div that allows searching and filtering no longer comes up.
I'm on chrome but this happens in IE as well:

There are no errors in Google Chrome Console (55.0.2883.87 m).  A video's worth a 1000 words, if I still don't make any sense watch it here:

http://www.screencast.com/t/nKF8mOvkKFF

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  _Now_ I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Lack of freehand red circles on theses screenshots, too bad...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your detailed bug report.  The additional information helped me find and reproduce the bug.  I'm sorry I was not previously able to do so.

The issue is now fixed in production.